# A table in .md document included from external file

Tags: github, markdown, tabular

Is there an elegant way how to include table from an external file in markdown document rendered by GitHub?

Non elegant solutions I can think of:

1. include it as image (this one is really really ugly)
2. use Rmarkdown and print table using R (wont be rendered by default)

Just to give a bit of explanation. I am using a set of `README.md` files in my git repository (hosted by GitHub), so it is really clear to browse repo online, because GitHub renders automatically `README.md` file in every subdirectory.

I am algorithmically generating summary tables that should be included in those documents. It would be way more elegant if that table could be read from external file, because I do not want to write scripts that will modify `README.md` files directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to include files within markdown. So you need a "preprocessing" stage to generate the markdown which is then shown on Github (or rendered with normal markdown tools).

What Github supports is [a basic table layout](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/), which you'd need to render:

## Solution 1: scripting

You could add something like this to your `README.md`:

```
<!-- TABLE_GENERATE_START -->

| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |

<!-- TABLE_GENERATE_END -->
```

And then have a script which pulls in the external table, reformats it to match the github format and puts it between the two comment.

## Solution 2: pandoc

Pandoc is a document converter framework with many possible inputs and outputs. If you're up to learn another tool you could

1. reformat you table into a markdown file using [csv2table](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-csv2table) into `table.md`
2. create a `readme_header.md` and `readme_footer.md` with the markdown before/after the table
3. merge the three files with `cat readme_header.md table.md readme_footer.md > REAME.md`

Of course you can also do a mixture of both solutions, e.g. generate `table.md` using a script and merge using `cat`

Comment: It is not exactly what I want, because it requires execution of another script. However, with makefile it wont be that painful. I think I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: including of other files within markdown is not supported in the default markdown format. Now, github has their own flavour of markdown (as there are a *lot* of flavours out there), but this one [only supports tables directly, no include files](https://help.github.com/categories/writing-on-github/)

Comment: @Slim: I added pandoc as a possibility to the answer

Comment: A colleague just pointed me to specialised tool for moreless this: https://github.com/jreese/markdown-pp